# Non blocking glReadPixels of depth values with PBO

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, glreadpixels, pbo

I am reading a single pixel's depth from the framebuffer to implement picking. Originally my glReadPixels() was taking a very long time (5ms or so) and on nVidia it would even [burn 100% CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311673/glreadpixels-burns-up-all-cpu-cycles-of-a-single-core) during that time. On Intel it was slow as well, but with idle CPU.

Since then, I used the PixelBufferObject functionality, **PBO**, to make the glReadPixels asynchronous and also double buffered using [this well known example](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).

This approach works well, and let's me make a glReadPixels() call asynchronous **but only if I read RGBA** values. If I use the same PBO approach to read depth values, the glReadPixels() blocks again.

Reading RGBA: glReadPixels() takes 12µs.

Reading DEPTH: glReadPixels() takes 5ms.

I tried this on nVidia and Intel drivers. With different format/type combinations. I tried:

```
glReadPixels( srcx, srcy, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0 );
```

and:

```
glReadPixels( srcx, srcy, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, 0 );
```

and:

```
glReadPixels( srcx, srcy, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV, 0 );
```

None of these would result in an asynchronous glReadPixels() call. But if I read RGBA values with the following call:

```
glReadPixels( srcx, srcy, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
```

then the glReadPixels() returns immediately, thus no longer blocks.

Before reading the single pixel, I do:

```
glReadBuffer( GL_FRONT );
glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboid );
```

And I create the double buffered PBO with:

```
glGenBuffers( NUMPBO, pboids );
for ( int i=0; i<NUMPBO; ++i )
{
    const int pboid = pboids[i];
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboid );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, DATA_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_READ );
    ...
```

I create my framebuffer using SDL2 with depth size 24, stencil size 8, and the default double buffer.

I am using OpenGL Core Profile 3.3 on Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: What is the actual format of your depth buffer? What happens if you render to an FBO with a specific OpenGL image format?

Comment: @nicol How do I find out? Can I query that? I request 24b depth and 8b stencil from SDL2, so could be expecting GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8 perhaps?

Comment: "Before reading the single pixel, I do `glReadBuffer( GL_FRONT );`" That;s only affecting the color buffers, there is no double buffering for the depth buffer, so it might actually explain the differences. It is hard to tell what exactly is happening, because the rest of your render loop is unknown, but it is possible that you force a synchronization even in your PBO code path (maybe just with some previous frames instead of the recent one).

Comment: @derhass I don't actually read the pixel depth (via glMapBuffer) **until the next frame** so there is no synchronization going on. The glReadPixel should have triggered an async operation and return immediately (as it does for RGBA). But it does not, for reading depth.

Comment: Well, for the Intel case, mesa is nice enough to tell you what's going on (use a debug callback!): `intel_texsubimage_blorp: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT not supported; intelReadPixels: fallback to CPU mapping in PBO case; CPU mapping a busy "isl-miptree" BO stalled and took 33.192 ms.`. Which will lead you to [this bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106800). What nvidia does, I don't know.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I can’t get better than .3 ms which adds up if I’m using this to generate results from a dozen sensors.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't actually read the pixel depth (via glMapBuffer) until the next frame so there is no synchronization going on. The glReadPixel should have triggered an async operation and return immediately (as it does for RGBA). But it does not, for reading depth.

That would require there to be two depth buffers. But there *aren't*. Multi-buffering refers to the number of *color buffers*, since those are what actually get displayed. Implementations pretty much never give you multiple depth buffers.

In order to service a read from the depth buffer, that read has to happen before "the next frame" takes place. So there would need to be synchronization.

Generally speaking, it's best to read from your own images. That way, you have complete control over things like format, when they get reused, and the like, so that you can control issues of synchronization. If you need two depth buffers so that you can read from one while using the other, then you need to create that.

And FYI: reading from the default framebuffer at all is dubious due to [pixel ownership issues](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Ownership_Test) and such. But reading from the *front* buffer is pretty much always the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense, but I do disagree with one thing: _"So there would need to be synchronization."_ Yes, but not for the glReadPixels() call, OpenGL doesn't know _when_ I will access the PBO. That synchronization could at most be forced at the glMapBuffer() call. But I observe the sync in the glReadPixels() call. I'm considering writing 8bit depth to ALPHA channel and use that instead, as reading async framebuffer depth seems impossible?

Comment: @Bram: Stop reading from the default framebuffer. That's the answer. Just stop doing it. I don't know why you would rather completely destroy your depth buffer by using 8-bits rather than just creating an FBO like everyone else. "*That synchronization could at most be forced at the glMapBuffer() call.*" No, it would have to be before that. You yourself said that you will render a frame before your map call. Since that rendering will *overwrite* the depth buffer, the read has to happen before any overwriting takes place.

Comment: Thx. I will study off-screen rendering instead then. Ok, sync would happen before the mapbuffer, but also after readpixels, not in readpixels. Probably when presenting framebuffer? Note about alpha: I would still use normal 24b depth for render, but fragment shader just copies fragment's z into the alpha channel for picking purpose. HIgh precision depth for z-test, low-precision copy for picking.